# encapsulated success after AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

How to resolve this JSON data?

```
success{"data": [{"id":"1","name":"something1"},{"id":"2","name":"something2"},{"id":"3","name":"something3"}] }
```

JSON data is encapsulated inside the success.

Server script return just like this:

```
echo '{"data": '. $jsondata .' }';
```

Comment: Post your JS/jQuery code, we don't know what you want to do.

Comment: how did you get that JSON data? can you post the code?

Comment: My question is why it is encapsulated with success{ }? All my codes are correct and It works on the other programs.

Answer (score 0):

To print json data try json_encode method. Try this, it was working for me

```
echo json_encode(array("data"=> $jsondata));
```